# Designing selectbox in joomla

Tags: javascript, css

I have a selectbox in which options are coming from a module. Following is its code.

```
<div id="dropdown">
<form action="" method="post" name="country"><label for="country"></label>
<select id="country" name="country" onchange="this.form.submit()">


<?php

    $rows = Array('UAE', 'SA', 'OMAN');

foreach($rows as $row){ 

    if($row == $session->get('cont')){ 

        $isSelected = ' selected="selected"'; 
    } 
    else { 
        $isSelected = ''; 
    } 

    echo "<option ".$isSelected.">".$row."</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
</form>
</div>
```

Now I want to show country flags with each option. Please suggest if there is any java-script plugin which I can use or any other simple way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried a search for `country flag drop down jquery` or similar? There are many options, personally I've used [this jQuery plugin](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/countries-dropdown-flags) earlier. You should be able to integrate it with your existing code by editing the `echo` statement.

Basically, you have to load the included .js and .css files, and make sure jQuery is included in your template.

```
//include scripts in header. (Add jQuery if needed.)
JHtml::_('script', JUri::base() . 'path/to/your/files/jquery.dd.min.js');
JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::base() . 'path/to/your/files/dd.css', array(), true);
JHtml::_('stylesheet', JUri::base() . 'path/to/your/files/flags.css', array(), true);

//initiate the script
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#country").msDropdown();
  })
');
```

Now modify your `echo` statement to something like this:

```
echo "<option ".$isSelected." value='".$row."' data-image='/path/to/your/files/blank.gif' data-imagecss='flag ".strtolower($row)."' data-title='".$row."'>".$row."</option>;
```

You might have to tweak the code a bit to work, I haven't tested it, but it's worth a shot.

Another alternative (might be easier) is the [Country Picker jQuery plugin](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/country/), but it uses a `<div>` element instead of a regular dropdown list, and you would have to edit your PHP loop.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Lodder, as usually I'd like to ask why... ;) [Joomla Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript) says `JHtml::script(Juri::base() . 'path/to/your/files/jquery.dd.min.js');`, you changed it to `JHtml::_('script', JUri::base() . 'path/to/your/files/jquery.dd.min.js');`, what's the difference?

Comment: If I rightly remember, `JHtml::script` was the older method. I'll get this confirmed tonight though

Comment: Ok so just found out that they are in fact the same, but your method is apparently slightly faster as it's doesn't go through as much processing. I've just simply used the `JHtml::_('script'` approach constantly but you can rollback the edit if you wish ;)

Comment: Thanks for looking it up, it's good to know the difference, although it probably doesn't matter in this case.